# Next 13 Link - not scrolling to specific section in the same page

Tags: next.js

This is the [site](https://asilbekdev.vercel.app/) i've been building with Nextjs 13. Clicking on the header links are expected to scroll to specific sections, like:

```
// app/layout.tsx
<Link href='/#about'>About</Link>

// app/page.tsx
<section id='about'>About section</section>
```

But they are not working, the `a` tag is working but the `Link`

I have checked if i have typo or smth, everything looks correct

Answer (score 0):

You have a forward slash before your link address

Change

```
// app/layout.tsx
<Link href='/#about'>About</Link>
```

to this

```
// app/layout.tsx
<Link href="#about'>About</Link>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter, by this i'm forwarding to home page if user is in another page. I also did that, didn't work